# What is the correct way of doing onload for image tags?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am using Onload() to know when an image has been loaded. It has worked for years and still is working on my computer and can be found in the w3schools reference http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_img_onload.asp

I ran one of my few pages that have that through the validator and it does not like me using onload with image tags.

```
<a href='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer'>
<img src='./player/embed/get_flash_player.gif'  alt='Get Adobe Flash player' onload="triggercounter('test','Flash Failed') "/>
</a>
```

What is the preferred way to trigger an event when an image has loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the validator error message most probably because you are validating against HTML 4.01 or XHTML 1.0, which do not allow `onload` on `img` (only on `body` and `frameset`). HTML5 allows it on any element.

This is just the formal side of the matter. Whether the method actually works in browsers is a completely different matter.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, avoid w3schools - the site's abhorrently out of date and incorrect on nearly everything - and isn't even associated with the W3C at all.

Then, simply change your `onLoad` to `onload` - HTML5/XHTML element attributes are lowercase and case-sensitive. Here's a handly list of 'global' attributes you can stick on *nearly* every HTML tag: [8. Global attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/global-attributes.html)

Comment: I already have it in lower case and it works fine. All need to do is ignore the w3school validator on that point and all is well?

Comment: What doctype are you using for the page? If it's a vaild HTML doctype `onload` should not be throwing any error: is it specifically throwing an "attribute not allowed" error, or a syntax error on the *content* of your `onload`? (Also, there is no "w3school" validator: they offload it to the official validator.w3.org site)

Comment: HTML5 is not case sensitive in attribute names, except in XHTML (XML) serialization.